# SwiftData with ValueTransformer similar to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift-data

In Core Data, you are able to use `ValueTransformer` to transform individual attributes to/from core data. This would be useful in cases like encrypting/decrypting certain attributes when storing/fetching from managed context.

Is there a similar way with SwiftData? I would like to save my data encrypted but have it decrypted in my `@Query` variable.

I need this for iOS.

Here is an example of using `ValueTransformer` via core data (credit: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/valuetransformer-core-data/):

```swift
override public func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let color = value as? UIColor else { return nil }
    
    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        return data
    } catch {
        assertionFailure("Failed to transform `UIColor` to `Data`")
        return nil
    }
}

override public func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let data = value as? NSData else { return nil }
    
    do {
        let color = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data as Data)
        return color
    } catch {
        assertionFailure("Failed to transform `Data` to `UIColor`")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `@Attribute(.transformable(by: <some transformer>)` together  with a `ValueTransformer` subclass you create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion in the comment from [@joakim-danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) worked beautifully :)

Essentially it is Core Data's `ValueTransformer` hooked into SwiftData. The below example converts between `Date` and `String`.

This is the SwiftData model `Item`:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    @Attribute(.transformable(by: DateValueTransformer.name.rawValue))
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

This is the `ValueTransformer` subclass, which persists the date as an encoded string:

```swift
import Foundation

@objc(DateValueTransformer)
class DateValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    var randomKey = "nothing"
    
    private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSDate.self
    }
    
    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let date = value as? Date else { return nil }
        
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date) + randomKey
        print("transform: \(dateString)")
        
        do {
            return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dateString, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Failed to transform `Date` to `Data(String)`")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let dateData = value as? Data else { return nil }
        do {
            guard let dateString = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSString.self, from: dateData as Data) as? String
            else { return nil }
            print("reverse: \(dateString)")
            
            return dateFormatter.date(from: String(dateString.dropLast(randomKey.count)))
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Failed to transform `Data(String)` to `Date`")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension DateValueTransformer {
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: DateValueTransformer.self))
    
    public static func register(randomKey: String) {
        let transformer = DateValueTransformer()
        transformer.randomKey = randomKey
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

In order to demonstrate how to pass dynamic values to the `ValueTransformer`, this snippet registers an instance of `DateValueTransformer` with a custom `randomKey`:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct SwiftDataExperimentApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        DateValueTransformer.register(randomKey: "something")
        
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}
```

When storing an instance of `Item` through SwiftData, you will get the following console output:

```bash
transform: 2023-10-23 09:56:53something
reverse: 2023-10-23 09:56:53something
```

It shows that our custom `randomKey` is also working.