# Formatting units and measurements. Why does Units init from symbol not produce same result as static init

Tags: swift, units-of-measurement

Recently I came across a quite curious behavior regarding units and measurements in Swift which I can't understand. After creating measurements with units created with a static UnitMass accessor I can properly format them and receive sensible outputs:

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: 42.0, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
measurement.formatted() // -> "42 kg" correct
```

When creating a measurement using a UnitMass created using init with its symbol I get wrong outputs

```
let anotherMass = UnitMass(symbol: UnitMass.kilograms.symbol)
let anotherMeasurement = Measurement(value: 42.0, unit: anotherMass)
anotherMeasurement.formatted() // -> "0 μg" wrong
```

The same happens when using a `MeasurementFormatter` instead of accessing `formatted` on the measurement. What is interesting: When debugging this in a playground and inspecting the outputs anotherMass and anotherMeasurement seem to be valid and produce sensible values:
[image: screenshot of Swift Playground with collapsed debug info]

Complete Playground

```
import UIKit

let mass = UnitMass.kilograms
let anotherMass = UnitMass(symbol: mass.symbol)

let measurement = Measurement(value: 42.0, unit: mass)
let anotherMeasurement = Measurement(value: 42.0, unit: anotherMass)

let formatted = measurement.formatted()
let anotherFormatted = anotherMeasurement.formatted()
```

Unfortunately I think I can't just use the static init because I want to store a unit in a SwiftData model and because UnitMass is not Codable I can only store the symbol representation. Therefor I need to work with `init(symbol:)` when converting back to a Unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init` that you are using is declared in [`Unit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unit/1690760-init). It won't know anything about `UnitMass`, and won't see that your symbol to be the same symbol as `UnitMass.kilograms`, and return `UnitMass.kilograms`. After all, if it worked this way, you wouldn't be able to create new units with the same symbol as existing units. `Unit.init` just creates a brand new unit with that symbol, unrelated to any other units.

Also note how [`Dimension.init(symbol:converter)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dimension/1823633-init) is used to create your custom unit. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dimension#1891928)

> The simplest way to define a custom unit is to create a new instance of an existing `NSDimension` subclass using the `init(symbol:converter:)` method.

This presumably also applies to `Unit.init(symbol:)`.

If you want to store a unit in SwiftData, a workaround would be to store the `Data` representation of the `Unit` (which you can get from `NSKeyedArchiver` since `Unit` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`). You can also try storing it as a `@Attribute(.transformable)` using [`NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecureunarchivefromdatatransformer) like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77341306/5133585) shows.

Alternatively, you can also store a conversion coefficient. You can get this by getting `(unit.converter as? UnitConverterLinear).coefficint`. Then use `Dimension.init(symbol:converter)` to recreate your unit, as a custom unit with the same conversion factor. However, you still lose localisation in the formatting this way.

Comment: Great explanation thank you. Seems like my assumption that symbol is unique for a Unit was just incorrect.

Comment: Went with the KeyedArchiver solution and it seems to work like a charm :)